# How to show the order of vectors doesn't matter when proving affine independence

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

> $v_0,v_1,...,v_k$ are **affinely independent** iff $v_1-v_0,
>  v_2-v_0,...,v_k-v_0$ is linearly independent.

If I were given a finite set of (affinely independent) vectors with numerical coefficients, for example, I could easily rename the vectors (choose any vector in the set to be $v_0$) and show affine independence. But I have no idea how to do this for an arbitrary set of vectors with arbitrary coefficients.

Comment: So you are saying that you have some arbitrarily large collection of vectors, and you want to know if you can renumber these and therefore choose one element to be $v_0$?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly it

Answer (score 1):

You could note the the matrix transforming $v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0,\ldots,v_n-v_0$
to say $v_0-v_1,v_2-v_1,\ldots,v_n-v_1$ is non-singular.

Alternatively you could give a more symmetric condition for affine (in)dependence, for instance, $v_0,\ldots v_n$ is affinely independent
iff the only $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ with both
$\sum\lambda_i=0$ and $\sum\lambda_iv_i=0$ is $(0,0,\ldots,0)$.